# camunda application not in the cockpit

Tags: java, spring, camunda

I created a `Camunda + Spring App` as described [here](https://docs.camunda.org/get-started/spring/) and deployed it as described in the documentation:

```
mavn package war:war
```

and then copied the `war file` to `$CAMUNDA_HOME/server/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/webapps``

Also I defined the `pools` as `executable`, but I can't see my app in the cockpit.

I also took a look at `catalina.out`and there's no error in there

```
05-Jun-2017 14:39:24.119 INFO [localhost-startStop-11] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /Users/paulcurcean/Downloads/camunda-bpm-tomcat-7.6.0/server/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/webapps/dronedelivery-0-SNAPSHOT.war has finished in 4,042 ms
```

Comment: Did you try the mentioned example "as is", without customization?

Comment: Yes. On two different laptops.